# MDI Single Instance C#.. how to achieve that?

Tags: c#, mdi

I found the following code in codeproject for single instance.

```
frmSChild objfrmSChild = frmSChild.GetChildInstance();
objfrmSChild.MdiParent = this;
objfrmSChild.Show();
objfrmSChild.BringToFront();
```

It is working fine. But it only works once.

I open the that `frmSChild` for 2 or 3 times. it will bring forwards that form.

But if I close that form and open again. there is an error stating `cannot detect an exposed ojbect`.

How to modify the code to get it done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the form's `IsDisposed` property, and, if it's true, make a new instance.

Comment: Hi, I checked the disposed property with try-catch. I put the above code in the try and if it goes to catch statement I started a new form. It is OK for the Main form but.. the exception pop up when I close the subform for the second time that cannot access the disposed object.

Comment: @william: Don't use a `try / catch` block for expected conditions; it's unnecessarily slow.  You should be able to check `objfrmSChild.IsDisposed`.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/singleinstanceforms.aspx

Using Generic to create instance

EDIT by drachenstern

```
   vvv click here to edit, yeah?
```

Comment: Hi @Caos and welcome to StackOverflow. Is there any way you could edit your post (click the link underneath) and edit your answer to provide us more information on how we would use Generics to create the instance he needs?